# Return from fullscreen not working in iframe with "video" tag

Tags: video, shadowbox

i have this test page: http://fireflystudiosinc.co/test/test.html

The video is shown on a shadowbox iframe with "video" tag. When returning to normal view from fullscreen pressing the button, the page turns black and I have to reload the tour.

I think it as to do with the iframe and video, if I play the video without the "video" tag this wont happen, it works fine, but then It wont work as well on iPad/iphone and other.

I read that it might had to do with coding the size of the parent doc, etc properly in the JS file or other.

Ive been pulling my hair for several days now to no avail.

Any help with this would be enormously appreciated.